# add time delivery options and charge extra for it

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, delivery, time

I need to add an option for time deliveries which would be before 10 in the morning, before noon and before 4 p.m. and I need to put this somewhere in the order process... I would prefer to put this on shipping methods page where I also have a calendar but if this is not possible I would put it on the product description page where I have different colors and sizes so it would be an additional atribute. I'm wondering the following:

1. Is it possible to easily add THIS option in the checkout step where the customer selects the shipping options and how would I set that up?
2. If option number one is not possible - can I add this atribute to all of my 1000 products at the same time? We're talking about the product description page where customers select colors, sizes and so on

Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against adding this as an attributes to each product as customers could select conflicting options then what would you do?

You could checkout this plugin https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delivery-date-delivery-time.html or hire a Magento developer to write a custom plugin for you.